# Custom FormConstrol validation Problem (undefined value) in Angular7

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, validation

I have a function to check pesel (unique id in Poland); I packed it into this:

```
export function ValidatePESEL(control: FormControl) : { [s:string]: boolean } { 

code...

if(output === false) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { validPesel: true };
    }
}
```

Whatever I try I'm getting "ERROR TypeError: "control.value is undefined""

Comment: use `if(control && control.value){....here check your control.value...}`

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? Like how you add the validator the formControl/formGroup?

Comment: Eliseo answer is correct, this fixed problem.